# scraping results not limited according to the passed parameters - kimonolabs

Tags: kimono

i've tried to add the parameters "kimoffset" and "kimlimit" to the source url of my api, but this doesn't limit and/or shift the scraped results

my api's source url:
    http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g187791-Rome_Lazio-Hotels.html?kimlimit=10&kimoffset=100

are these parameter used for this?
why doesn't work?

the results in data preview area are always the same

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the server is ignoring your [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) `kimlimit=10&kimoffset=100`.